# Signing Mac App in Visual Studio for Mac (Xamarin)

Tags: macos, xamarin-studio, visual-studio-mac

I have a Mac app, created in Visual Studio for Mac. Before distributing, I would need to have the application bundle signed. However, looking at the project options, this is greyed out on my screen:

[image: Sign the application bundle greyed out]

According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/mac/deploy-test/publishing-to-the-app-store/signing, I should be able to select it and pull the Developer ID certificate from the keychain (which is present).

My question is; what causes this option to be greyed out?

The yellow triangle doesn't give any hint:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I was creating an installer and therefore assumed I needed the 'Developer ID Installer' certificate. However, it needed to be the 'Developer ID Application. After having that one in the keychain, the box became available.

Answer (score 3):

For me I had also to create a *'Mac Development'* certificate.